# Are bird statues the only way to save?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Aside from the occasional save prompt, the only way I've discovered to save thus far is with bird statues. This is very unusual, since previous Zelda games allowed you to save anywhere.

Are bird statues really the only way to save, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the bird statues are the only way to save. [This article](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/reviews/2011/11/review-skyward-sword-slashes-zeldas-sacred-cows.ars) mentions save points in dungeons, and I am assuming they are refering to the bird statues as well.

> There are save points scattered throughout the adventure, even in the middle of dungeons. This might sound like an obvious improvement, but it will be taken as something approaching heresy by the more traditionalist of Zelda fans. If you die, you can continue at the last save point with all of the items you've found. Nintendo clearly wants players of all skill levels to be able to finish the adventure.

Comment: Owl statues weren't the only way to save in Majora's Mask, the Song of Time is the primary save method.

Comment: Hm, I misremember then. :( I will edit that out.

Comment: The Song of Time didn't help very much if you were in the middle of something, to be fair.